# Iphone app - show phone pad above the tabbar

Tags: iphone

I am working on iphone app that has tab bar at the bottom of the screen. I need to show phone pad like the apple iphone's default phonepad when making call above the tab bar.
How can i do it?
if it is not possible, do i need images for each number to style them to look like iphone phonepad or this can be done by changing background color etc of the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant "can I show the native dial pad from iPhone", the answer is no, you have to roll your own. There is no documented API to show the native dial pad.

There are many ways to do that. One of them is what you mentioned: create images for each button and a UILabel to show the number being dialed.